# How to enter star * inside a string in shell

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell

How can I include `*` inside a string?

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is a simple calculator using select statement
echo -n 'Insert 1st operand: '
read first
echo -n 'Insert 2nd operand: '
read second
echo 'Select an operator:'
operators="+ - * /"
select op in $operators
do let "result=${first}${op}${second}"
   break
done
echo -e "Result = $result"
```

When I run this code, `*` will list all files in current directory as `select` choices. I tried to escape it with `\*` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shall expands its parameters. But then `select` expands its parameters too. The shell expands `\*` to just `*`, which doesn't help, since `select` then expands that `*`. You need something that expands to `\*`, which would be `\\*`.

Alternatively, just use: 
`select op in + - \* /;`
or:
`select op in "$operators"`

Answer (score 1):

First you can put $operator with double quotes to be sure that there is no interpretation. Select display correctly the list of parameters
BTW the end of code doesn't work as expected : it display the first and the second operand but not the operator

Answer (score 0):

Arrays help out quite often in shell scripting when you experience difficulty using a string you've constructed dynamically.

```
$ operators=( + - '*' / )
$ PS3="choice? "
$ select o in "${operators[@]}"; do echo "$o $REPLY"; done
1) +
2) -
3) *
4) /
choice? 1
+ 1
choice? 2
- 2
choice? 3
* 3
choice? 4
/ 4
```